# I get double question marks when referring to labels inside figures

Tags: cross-referencing

I have some charts embedded in figures, and I want to be able to refer to them easily using the "Figure *x*" notation. I'm doing it like this (in this order):

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

...

\section*{Results}
...we performed a linear regression to obtain a standard curve 
(Figure~\ref{0:stdcurve})....

\pagebreak
\section*{Results (Graphs)}
\subsection*{Construction of Standard Graph for PNP}
\begin{figure}[h]   % Figure 1
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{kinematics-res/graph0-1}
    \caption{The standard curve for PNP.}
    \label{0:stdcurve}
\end{figure}
```

However, instead of getting the output "...to obtain a standard curve (Figure 1)...", I just get "...to obtain a standard curve (Figure **??**)..."

I also noticed that the PDFLaTeX compiler is generating warnings saying that it couldn't find the reference of the name `0:stdcurve`. Why am I getting these warnings?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to run LaTeX twice. The first time it figures out the reference numbers. On the second pass it fills in the reference numbers.

The following generates `...standard curve (Figure {??})` upon the first pass, but generates `...standard curve (Figure 1)...` upon the second pass:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 

\begin{document}
\section*{Results}
...we performed a linear regression to obtain a standard curve 
(Figure~\ref{0:stdcurve})....

\pagebreak
\section*{Results (Graphs)}
\subsection*{Construction of Standard Graph for PNP}
\begin{figure}[h]   % Figure 1
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{kinematics-res/graph0-1}
    \caption{The standard curve for PNP.}
    \label{0:stdcurve}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am using PDFLaTeX. Am I supposed to run that twice? I just did that, and it's not changing anything. If it's of any help, I am using Texmaker as my TeX IDE.

Comment: Run it twice, and don't delete the temporary files that get generated upon the first run.

Comment: Oooh...thanks for that. The "temporary files" bit was the important part. I have a stray `\nofiles` command stuck at the beginning of my file. Now I know that the .aux files that PDFLaTeX are actually very important for cross-references.

Comment: @GiantMarshmallow: That's why we always ask for a minimal example that you've actually tried. It's amazing what people miss out and then assume we'll all guess!

Comment: Still doesn't work for me -- neither in Kile nor in TeXStudio, and neither with PDFLatex nor with Xetex.

Comment: @sequence: Are you running pdflatex twice? Also, make sure you are not deleting the temporary files between the runs. If this does not work, I suggest you ask a new question and include a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

Comment: as Future Reference for anyone still having issues (like @sequence): The Label Name can't contain any special characters. (In German there are äöü for example, replace these with ae oe ue)