# Problem: wrong figure reference number

Tags: floats, hyperref, captions

I have the following problem. Here's the code I use

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno,oneside]{report}  % openright
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath,stmaryrd}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts, amssymb, amscd, enumerate,mathrsfs, color}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
bla bla bla (see \ref{fig1})
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
\caption{Description.}\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Before the beginning of the figure, I write "bla bla bla (see \ref{fig1})" but, once compiled, in \ref{fig1} appears "??" instead of the number of the figure (which is 0.0.1)..

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Thank You

Comment: you need to run latex multiple times (at least twice) for cross references to resolve

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It does not work with multiple (three, four,..) runnings..

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31786/i-get-double-question-marks-when-referring-to-labels-inside-figures

Comment: I just tested your document and it resolves giving 1 on the second run

Comment: you say the figure number is 0.0.1 but the code above produces `Figura 1`. Make sure that the example posted does actually show the problem, it could be a problem in code you have not shown.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're sure. The problem is the command "\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{\addtocounter{figure}{1}{\bf Figura \thesection.\thefigure} \ {\it #1}}" that produces "??" in "\ref{fig1}". I comment this command and now it works. Anyway, how can I set that the name of the figure is written in bold (i.e. "Figure 1" in bold below the figure)? And how can I set the counter of the figure by section? Thank You

Comment: why are you loading several packages multiple times? also, what do you need the deprecated package `t1enc` for? clean up your code! it reduces error sources.

Comment: @Redeldio so this question isn't really answerable as it stands the code posted has no problem but there  was code not shown that completely breaks it. If you want to control the formatting of captions, use the caption package. I suggest this question is closed as a duplicate of the question I linked to.

Comment: @Redeldio Since you are already using the caption package: Try `\usepackage[labelfont=bf,textfont=it,within=section]{caption}` instead of re-defining `\caption` on your own.