# \label and \ref is not working properly, \ref typesets?

Tags: cross-referencing

I am working in `book` document class. I am using `\label` and `\ref` command but `\ref` commands does not give expected output. I am sharing a sample code.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{equation}\label{pyth}
c^2 = a^2 + b^2
\end{equation}
\ref{pyth} is a Pythagorean theorem
\end{document}
```

and its typeset file is

[image]

Kindly help.

Comment: did you compile twice?

Comment: No. @UlrikeFischer

Comment: well then do it, references are resolved in the second compilation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, it is working, but its showing in red color. Is it normal?

Comment: @prashantsharma: Did you load the `hyperref` package with the `colorlinks` option? If so, this is the expected behaviour. If you don't want colored hyperlinks, use the `hidelinks` option instead. For more infomation see here: [options for appearance of links in hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50747/134144)

Comment: no, not with your example in the question. There shouldn't be any color.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, you are right.

Comment: @leandriis you pointed out rightly.

Comment: @prashantsharma: Your question seems to be very similar to this one: [I get double question marks when referring to labels inside figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31786/134144). Would you agree to close yours as a duplicate?